# how to execute a function after end another in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have a query that I have a function which response to a server, so it takes a while and when it tries to execute the other function, an error occurs. Since the function responds an array from which comes from the server and when the other function requests that, even It does not have. Have to solve this. example :

```
responseServer(tarea) {
     return fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({ refresh: false })
        global.refresh = false
        let data = [];
        let Milestone = [];

        Object.values(responseJson.summary).forEach(item => {
          data = data.concat(item);
        });

        const result = ["Milestone"]
          .reduce((total, category) => ({
            ...total,
            [category]: data.filter(line => line.includes(category)) 
          }), {})

        Object.values(result.Milestone).forEach(item => {
          Milestone = Milestone.concat(item)
        });

        this.setState({
          Milestone: Milestone
        })
      })
}
```

and another function

```
sacarPorcentaje(item) {
 this.responseServer(item)
 let summaryCopy = this.state.Milestone.map(data => {return data.split(",")})
      console.log(summaryCopy)
      var Okeys = 0;
      var total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < summaryCopy.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < summaryCopy[i].length; j++){
          if(summaryCopy[i][j] === "OK") {
            Okeys = Okeys + 1
          }
        }
        total = total + 1 
      }
      console.log(Okeys)
      console.log(total)
}
```

Comment: sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

You should update `sacarPorcentaje()` to `async` function. then `await` the function call, will resolve your issue

```
async sacarPorcentaje (item) {
 await this.responseServer(item)
 let summaryCopy = this.state.Milestone.map(data => {return data.split(",")})
      console.log(summaryCopy)
      var Okeys = 0;
      var total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < summaryCopy.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < summaryCopy[i].length; j++){
          if(summaryCopy[i][j] === "OK") {
            Okeys = Okeys + 1
          }
        }
        total = total + 1 
      }
      console.log(Okeys)
      console.log(total)
}
```

There is also one more solution for this issue. please search how to use `Promise` in `JS`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `then` when you call `responseServer` function in `sacarPorcentaje` function.

```
sacarPorcentaje(item) {
 this.responseServer(item).then(() => {
 let summaryCopy = this.state.Milestone.map(data => {return data.split(",")})
      console.log(summaryCopy)
      var Okeys = 0;
      var total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < summaryCopy.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < summaryCopy[i].length; j++){
          if(summaryCopy[i][j] === "OK") {
            Okeys = Okeys + 1
          }
        }
        total = total + 1 
      }
      console.log(Okeys)
      console.log(total)
   }
}
```